# Banana plant leave stems broken, cut off completely or splint it?

Tags: banana

I bought a 2ft tall banana plant with some pretty large leaves from a nursery. It is in good health but unfortunate a few large stems broke during transport. It is still connected but no longer able to support the weight of the large leaf.

I tried to splinter the stem with a pencil and tape to hold it up. Is this a worthless effort? Should I cut the stems off?

How fast can I expect the stems to grow back? This is planted in a 16 gallon pot on a south facing balcony. What are some tips to make the recovery fast?

Comment: Who transported your Banana tree?  I would get some Mycorrhizae fungal spores, keep that plant watered like heck but not allowing it to sit in water.  No fertilizer right now. Using a pencil for a support might work just fine.  Can't possibly hurt anything.  Those leaves are what a plant has to have to MAKE their own food.  Send a picture, please.

Answer (score 1):

I grew banana plants from a (free) root again this winter. Got 6 pups (sprouts). When the leaves overgrew my growth chamber, about 3 feet, I cut them down to within a few inches of the ground. It is NOT spring here yet. All the pups are growing back.

Answer (score 0):

Do not cut the leaves and do not splint the leaves, let them hang naturally and die. This is how banana trees grow. I realize the leaves broke artificially but it doesn’t matter. The leaves act like airborne mulch and help keep humidity close to the stem of the plant.

Mist your banana plant daily. It comes from a VERY moist environment. It will thank you.